# unable to browse internet as it needs to be authenticate via server reachable via IE 5 or above

Tags: internet

I have recently installed ubuntu (ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64), the problem is that I have a DSL connection (wired connection) which need to authenticate via server and this server can be reached via IE5 (Internet Explorer 5) or above. I'm running windows 7 along with ubuntu. Please suggest how I do install Internet explorer there....I have tried searching for downloading file from the internet but couldn't find any for ubuntu...Please help!!

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Is this a PPPOE connection? If so, see if this helps http://chetangole.com/blog/2008/10/how-to-start-configur-bsnl-broadband-connection-on-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can't install IE5 (or any IE) in an operating system other than Windows (except for some older versions that worked on Mac if I'm correct).

You should me able to use Firefox instead - which is installed by default and way better than IE.

Comment: mozilla is already installed but seems not to be working since as I  mentioned server needs to be reached via Internet Explorer 5 or above only.

Comment: @user232379 You can try to ask the server administrator to allow authentication from browsers other than IE. But if this is the authentication needed to establish the DSL connection then you can try to create a new connection as DSL and enter the authentication details on the screen given.

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to the internet using an authenticated DSL connection, you need to set your username and password in the network connections. To do this, follow the procedure:

1.Type "network" in your dash, and click on "Network Connections".

[image: network connections in dash]

2.When a window such as the one below pops up, click on "DSL" and then "Add".

[image: add a dsl connection]

3.When a dialog box such as the one below pops up, add *your username* and *your password* in the relevant fields.

[image: add username and password]

4.Next, if you are assigned a static IP address by your Internet Service Provider, then click on "Manual" method and add the IP address, Netmask and Gateway and DNS server provided by your ISP in the relevant fields. If you have a dynamic IP, click on "Automatic PPPoE".

[image: add ip address and dns]

5.Finally, click on save and see if you are connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If Jobin's solution works for you, don't waste your time installing IE, except if you really need it.

You cannot find any IE for Linux. However, you can make it work through Playonlinux or wine.

The easiest way to make IE work on Linux is to install PlayOnLinux; you need the last version, which you can get here:

http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html

make sure the package wine1.6-i386:i386 is installed.

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.6-i386:i386
```

Once PlayOnLinux is installed, simply run it and on the top, click install, then internet, then Internet Explorer 8 (or any version you want). Just follow the installation instructions. It will download and install automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla Firefox and Chromium can be used as Internet Explorer 5.5 and above once you install an extension named 'User-Agent Switcher' which can be found in the ADDON's page, and which will add a button in your toolbar, and allow you to change browser identification settings to IE6 or IE7.

Firefox also features another addon called 'User Agent Quick Switch' which allows you to quickly and manually change browser identification to whatever you want.

Konqueror can also be used as Internet Explorer 5.5 and above if you change some settings that are to be found in: Settings - Configure Konqueror - Web Browsing - Browser Identification. You can press 'NEW' and change settings to IE6 or IE7 but you need to know your ISP provider web address to be able to identify Konqueror as Internet Explorer.